# How can extract sub-components using JMagick

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, jmagick

In one of the my project i need to process the image(Consider any ad banner displayed on most of the websites) and need to extract sub-components like logo, buttons and all from that image banner. So i am using java wrapper "JMagick" over imagemagick. All your help will be very grateful , thanks all in advance.